# If $b_j>0$ for every $j$ and if $\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}b_j$ converges then prove that $\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}(b_j)^3$ converges or diverges.

Tags: analysis

If $b_j>0$ for every $j$ and if $\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}b_j$ converges then prove that $\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}(b_j)^3$ converges or diverges.

I believe it to be true if the positivity hypothesis holds, but I am not sure otherwise...

What if $b_j=\frac{-1^j}{\sqrt{j}}$ then it converges by the zero test but the square of that doesn't converge via the p-test... I am confused how without the positivity hypothesis, we can make the claim that $b_j^3$ converges. If we could always say $b_j^2<b_j$ I would buy it but I don't know if that is the case...

Without the positivity hypothesis I would conjecture that there is convergence as well. I am having trouble coming up with a good proof but my thoughts are as follows. Since 3 is an odd power (like 1), the signs of $b_j^3$ will alternate (if the did for the $b_j$) in the same way as the $b_j$. Furthermore, as $j$ gets large, the $b_j\rightarrow 0$ and cubing a number less than 1 makes the number smaller. So the values should just go to zero faster and respecting the sign changes. Thus, it would converge in theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sum b_j$ converges then $b_j\rightarrow 0$.

For $j$ large enough you have $0<b_j<1 \Rightarrow 0<b_j^2<b_j$

By multiplying with $b_j$ again you get $0<b_j^3<b_j^2\Rightarrow 0<b_j^3<b_j$

Then $\sum b_j^3$ converges by comparison test.

Comment: thank you for the help. Would it be multiplying by $b_j^2$ though in order to get $b_j^3$?

Comment: you multiply with $b_j$ one time to get $b_j^2<b_j$ and one more time to get $b_j^3<b_j^2$, then $b_j^3<b_j$ follows by transitivity

Comment: What if $b_j=\frac{-1^j}{\sqrt{j}}$ then it converges by the zero test but the square of that doesn't converge via the p-test... I am confused how without the positivity hypothesis, we can make the claim that $b_j^3$ converges. If we could always say $b_j^2<b_j$ I would buy it but I don't know if that is the case...

Comment: Without the positivity hypothesis I would conjecture that there is convergence as well. I am having trouble coming up with a good proof but my thoughts are as follows. Since 3 is an odd power (like 1), the signs of $b_j^3$ will alternate (if the did for the $b_j$) in the same way as the $b_j$. Furthermore, as $j$ gets large, the $b_j\rightarrow 0$ and cubing a number less than 1 makes the number smaller. So the values should just go to zero faster and respecting the sign changes. Thus, it would converge in theory

Comment: You cannot remove positivity (or absolute convergence) condition. Think for example about the series $2-1-1+...+2n^{-1/3}-n^{-1/3}-n^{-1/3}+...$. It converges to zero, but $\sum b_j^3$ clearly diverges to $\infty$.